# How to get file contents from shared git repository which runs on same server

Tags: git

I have a shared repository (repository.git, there aren't project files, they are in intern git structure).

We are doing system for managing git repositories, those repo are on the same server.
And a problem is, that I need a latest version of file from master branch to print out. But i don't know how, I tried `git show --pretty=format:"%b" filename`, but it just gave me diff of two latest versions. But that's useless.

I also tried `git cat-files` but it need sha1 hash of file, path to file didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work: `git show master:filename`